# Android sqlite made easy

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I read at the Android documentation, and the "sqlite helper" is crazy complicated! Is there a way to not use it and maybe use standard sql commands instead? I come from the php mysql, that's my reference; I took a look at the php sqlite too and it also looks much easier.

UPDATE

Thanks soulreaver! Now, another question:
When would I want to use the sqlite helper ? what are the benefits ?

Comment: Everything's complicated if you don't understand it. Take some time and learn it.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it is a rant, not a question. If you wish to ask questions about what you gain from using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you are welcome to do so.

Comment: To who who put me on hold: ur stupid ! I made a clear question, that i paste here: "Is there a way to not use it and maybe use standard sql commands instead?", and I recieved a perfect answer from soulreaver. I cant see y u put me on hold? now i added a second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use raw `SQLite` queries [RawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). I can agree that sometimes for simple tasks using `SQLiteOpenHelper` doesn't help at all (It is usable for more complicated things though).

Comment: Thanks, happy to know that there is one! now I could add a second question...